# Adding nodes to xml file in javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

I am trying to add an entry to a xml file using javascript. The code below is supposed to add a node called book to this file. But it simply doesn't work. I have also tried some other code just to change an entry in the xml database, but also without success. So what is my fault?

**CODE:**

```
function loadXMLDoc(dname) {
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else {
    xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xhttp.open("GET",dname,false);
xhttp.send();
return xhttp.responseXML;
}

xmlDoc=loadXMLDoc("database.xml");

newNode = xmlDoc.createElement("entry");
newNode.nodeValue = "aaaaa";
x=xmlDoc.documentElement;
x.appendChild(newNode);
```

**XML FILE (database.xml):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<database>
<entry>
    <title>Everyday Italian</title>
    <content>Strange. I seem to get hungry about the same time every day!</content>
    <time>August 7, 2012, 6:24 PM</time>
    <comment>Giada De Laurentiis</comment>
</entry>
<entry>
    <title>I'm Hungry</title>
    <content>I really need something to eat!!</content>
    <time>August 7, 2012, 6:24 PM</time>
    <comment>Giada De Laurentiis</comment>
</entry>
</database>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading an XML file through the network, and I am guessing that you ARE modifying the XML document which is in **MEMORY** by adding a new node. But there is nothing in your code that would save the modified XML file from memory to a persistable medium. You could implement a POST or PUT method to write the file just as you implemented the GET method to read it. Of course, your web server should be configured to take such a PUT request and overwrite the original file.

Comment: Could you please give me an example on how to implement this POST OR PUT method??

Comment: That would depend entirely on which software you are using as a web server. Are you using IIS? or Apache? or NodeJS?

Comment: Fixed the whole thing with php. What a dumb idea to modify a file client side ;)